# Change handler for pytest fixture log_capture

Tags: python-2.7, pytest

Consider an example of test function

```
from testfixtures import log_capture
import logging

@log_capture(level=logging.ERROR)
def test_function(logs):
    logs.check()
```

It works fine but how about changing the default handler and loggers?
For changing the loggers I tried passing as an argument `names='my_logger'` but it throws an error

> ```
> l = LogCaptureForDecorator(names or None, install=False, **kw)
> ```
>
> TypeError: **init**() got multiple values for keyword argument 'names'

Comment: Where does `log_capture` come from? It is not part of `pytest`. Is it some plugin you're using?

Comment: @hoefling https://testfixtures.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#testfixtures.LogCapture